# UI hasn't alloc yet

Tags: android, seekbar

I write it in oncreateView of Fragment. But this control hasn't alloc yet so I can't getWidth of it. Help me plzzz. Can I set it in which method (onresume, onstart...)?

```
        seekbar1 = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.sbBar);

    if (seekbar1.getWidth() > 0){
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "alloc" (if you are talking about memory allocation). The problem is that the actual layout is done later, not in any of the Activity or Fragment lifecycle methods. This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114495/1418097

Comment: When does the layout finish? Can you share me some code relate them?

Comment: @user1857193 When this thing is called: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this works in your case

```
seekbar.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int w = seekbar.getWidth();
        }
    });
```